# Database design for grouped users with one account

Tags: database-design

(Web based application scenario)

I am trying to solve a problem given the following conditions:

1. There should be a user table and user_contact table which contains all information.The staff and a patient will inherit the details to remove redundancy of having the patient table a last name and first name and so as the staff table.
2. There is a family table which a patient table is referenced by its family_id to group family members.

Now. I am confused in the next condition

Accounts are issued per family, not per patient. Same username and password are used by patients under a single family. If i put the username and password attribute in the family, i would also have to put a username and password for the staff.
I have been taught that I should always avoid redundancy in tables. I am really having a hard time constructing a table for the last condition.

How can I acheive this? Should I create a table named Account and have attributes (id,username,password) and have it referenced as a foreign key by the family table and staff table?

OR

Should i create a table named Account with attributes (id,username,password,staff_id,family_id, type). In this design I am really not sure if it is a good one because one attribute between staff_id or family_id will be null which will always return a constraint because there is no value for the referenced parent table.

OR there is a better way to do this that isnt in any of my options?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been taught that I should always avoid redundancy in tables.

You have been taught well.

Create a password table.

```
Password
--------
User ID
Password
Account or Staff value
Account or Staff ID
```

The password **must be** salted and encrypted.  The value tells you whether the ID is for an account with family privileges or a staff member with staff privileges.

If it turns out that you need more than two values, you should create a Value class.

```
Value
-----
Value ID
Value Name
```

And perhaps a Value Permission class.

```
Value Permission
----------------
Value ID
Permission ID

Permission
----------
Permission ID
Permission
```

This is probably too fine-grained for your application.

Remember.  You can create thousands of tables as long as each table contains values that pertain to the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help you Codd.

Comment: Thanks @Gilbert for point out that the password should be encrypted and salted. I will add an additional table "Account" to store the username and then i will reference the password_id

Comment: If the password table's primary key is the user_id. What if the user is member of the family (A condition wherein another user with same last name is registered). I think I will encounter a problem then. Should it be better to reference an account id to the user table? In this case, every account of a user can be identified by the account id

Comment: @MLDS: I thought the family had one user id.  If it's called an account id, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you aren't sure about what is the best database structure to handle ill-defined or potentially fluid requirements, the best rule of thumb is to treat each thing of interest (whether tangible or intangible) as an entity/table.

In your case, you have accounts.  Some accounts are assigned to employees.  Some accounts are assigned to families.  Maybe in the future family accounts might be assigned to other kinds of individuals or groups?  No matter what, an account will always have certain stable attributes, like user ID and password.  Therefore make an account table.

Then you need to figure out how to relate your other entities to account.  I think you'll find pretty quickly that you want your family table and your staff table to point to account, not the other way around.  That's what makes the most sense.  At least until your boss tells you about the new requirement to allow multiple accounts per employee or family...

Comment: Sorry for being a little confused here. I just want to clarify, Do you mean that my family table and staff table should contain the foreign key account_id referencing their accounts? And, I have a user table with their details. Is it better to connect the account table to the user table?

Comment: @MLDS - Yes have the `account_id` on each of the family and staff tables.  As for a `USER` table versus an `ACCOUNT` table, think carefully about whether you actually make a distinction.  One real person (user) could potentially open many accounts.  However, does your organization _really_ want to make a distinction between real people and their logins?  I've found that most organizations really don't care about the people (from a database perspective).  Most places I've been involved with really stop at the login ID. You might want to combine USER and ACCOUNT into one table.

Comment: That was originally what I did. But to comply with the requirements, not every patient has a single account. If they belong in a family group, they will have the same account.

Comment: @MLDS - Sometimes names are just semantics, but sometimes semantics matter.  You might find that USER is something you want to avoid.  Maybe you should have a PATIENT table and an ACCOUNT table.  This may help to keep the idea of a flesh and blood person distinct from a User ID/password combination.  It doesn't change your structure, but it may help you keep in mind which columns belong to which tables and where your relationships (foreign keys) should go.